# Validation DropDownList outside grid

Tags: javascript, html

I have kendo dropdownlist and button submit. I want if the user not select anything in dropdown(position), there will be validation that inform the user must select one position at least at dropdown. Then, if the user has click the position, so the user can submit the data. I have used some method like "required" but not working.

> HTML

```
    <input id="dropdown" style="width:200px;" />
```

> JavaScript for kendoDropDownList (position)

```
$("#dropdown").kendoDropDownList({
    optionLabel: "- Select Position -",
    dataTextField: "functionName",
    dataValueField: "hrsPositionID",
    dataSource: {
    transport:{
        read: {
        url:  "./testjson.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: function() {
                return { 
                    method: "getDropdown",
                }
            }
        },
    },
    },  
    change: function(e){
        console.log(this.value());
        // $('#AccountingTree').data('kendoTreeView').homogeneous.read();
        homogeneous1.read();
        homogeneous2.read();
        homogeneous3.read();
        homogeneous4.read();
        homogeneous5.read();
        homogeneous6.read();
        homogeneous7.read();
        homogeneous8.read();
        homogeneous9.read();
        homogeneous10.read();
        homogeneous11.read();
        homogeneous12.read();
        homogeneous13.read();
        homogeneous14.read();
    }   
}).data('kendoDropDownList');
dropdownlist = $("#dropdown").data("kendoDropDownList");
```

For dropdownlist above, i"m using homogeneous data (treeview).

Anyone have any idea or reference on this question?

> JavaScript AJAX call for submit button

```
//AJAX call for button
    $("#primaryTextButton").click(function(){
        if($("#dropdown").data("kendoDropDownList").value() == ""){
            kendo.alert("Please select position.");
        }
    });
    $("#primaryTextButton").kendoButton();
    var button = $("#primaryTextButton").data("kendoButton");
    button.bind("click", function(e) {

    var test = $("#dropdown").val()

    $.ajax({
        url: "../DesignationProgramTemplate/testjson.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
                method: "addTemplate" ,
                id: test,
                progid: array
                },

                success: function (response) {
                if(response === "SUCCESS")
                {
                    kendo.alert("Data saved");

                }else
                { 
                    kendo.confirm("Update the data?")
                    .done(function(){
                        $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "../DesignationProgramTemplate/testjson.php",
                        data: {
                                method: "deleteTemplate" ,
                                id: test,
                                progid: array
                                },
                        success: function(){
                            kendo.alert("Data updated");
                        }
                        });
                    });  
                }   
                },
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
When you click the button, just get the value of the kendoDropDownList and do a 
conditional statement. Hope this helps. Happy Coding ;D

        //AJAX call for button
        $("#primaryTextButton").kendoButton();
        var button = $("#primaryTextButton").data("kendoButton");
        button.bind("click", function(e) {

        var test = $("#dropdown").data("kendoDropDownList").value();
        if(test == ""){
                kendo.alert("Please select position.");
        }
        else{
            $.ajax({
                url: "../DesignationProgramTemplate/testjson.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    method: "addTemplate" ,
                    id: test,
                    progid: array
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    if(response === "SUCCESS"){
                        kendo.alert("Data saved");
                    }
                    else{ 
                        kendo.confirm("Update the data?")
                        .done(function(){
                            $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "../DesignationProgramTemplate/testjson.php",
                            data: {
                                    method: "deleteTemplate" ,
                                    id: test,
                                    progid: array
                                    },
                            success: function(){
                                kendo.alert("Data updated");
                            }
                            });
                        });  
                    }   
                },
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: I have updated code above for submit button. And put also the code given by you. But, the ouput is kendo.confim are out first then the alert "please select position". Is it wrong line I put the code?

Comment: I updated the code. I removed the code earlier and move it inside your code and wrapped it into an if-else statement.